# Java 8 foreach add subobject to new list

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8

Is it possible in Java 8 to write something like this:

```
List<A> aList = getAList();
List<B> bList = new ArrayList<>();

for(A a : aList) {
    bList.add(a.getB());
}
```

I think it should be a mix of following things:

```
aList.forEach((b -> a.getB());
```

or

```
aList.forEach(bList::add);
```

But I can't mix these two to obtain the desired output.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here are a few ways

```
aList.stream().map(A::getB).forEach(bList::add);
// or
aList.forEach(a -> bList.add(a.getB()));
```

or you can even create `bList()` on the fly:

```
List<B> bList = aList.stream().map(A::getB).collect(Collectors.toList());
```